# Set boolean value to FALSE for each row in query with 'HAVING'?

Tags: sql, postgresql

(Sorry about the phrasing of the title.)

I have the following SQL query that retrieves all the rows I want:

```
SELECT
    app_activity.name 
FROM
    app_chatmessage
JOIN
    app_activity ON app_chatmessage.activity_id = app_activity.id
GROUP BY
    app_activity.name
HAVING
    COUNT(app_chatmessage.owner_id) = 1;
```

Now, the table `app_chatmessage` also has a column `seen`. I'd like to set this column to `FALSE` for all the rows returned by the aforementioned query. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Update app_chatmessage set seen='FALSE' where
activity_id in 
(
SELECT
    app_activity.id
 FROM
     app_chatmessage
 JOIN
      app_activity ON app_chatmessage.activity_id = app_activity.id
 GROUP BY
     app_activity.name
 HAVING
     COUNT(app_chatmessage.owner_id) = 1
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did just what I wanted.

Comment: The query planner probably transforms it to the same as an `UPDATE ... FROM ...` too.

Answer (score 0):

try below one

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT
    app_activity.name, SEEN,  COUNT(app_chatmessage.owner_id) over(partition by app_activity.name order by app_activity.name) CNT
FROM
    app_chatmessage
JOIN
    app_activity ON app_chatmessage.activity_id = app_activity.id
    )
    UPDATE CTE
    SET SEEN = FALSE
    WHERE CNT =1
```

Comment: You can't `UPDATE` a CTE term in PostgreSQL. Unlike MS SQL Server, CTEs can't produce updatable views, they're always materialized to tables.

Comment: @CraigRinger, I agree, but there is no information which we can say question is not related to SQL Server.

Comment: Um... the tags? It's tagged PostgreSQL, and more to the point, it's *not tagged [tag:sql-server]*. If you're going to give answers specific to Microsoft SQL Server, please follow the [tag:sql-server] tag not the [tag:sql] tag, which refers to *the SQL standard in general*, not Microsoft's unfortunately-named product.